# Is it possible to bundle a python version, dependencies and my program in one folder for distribution

Tags: python, software-distribution

I have finished my program and I need to send it to beta testers but they aren't very tech-savvy and won't know how to install python and pip install dependencies. and especially when i want to distribute to an even wider audience, i can't have them all have to set everything up.

I tried pyinstaller, but it doesn't include all or my image files, or my save database.

my issue is i don't know how to bundle everything together and make the program know wherethe python install is, where te dependencies are... etc

any help would be excellent. thanks!

Comment: Have you checked [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/setupscript.html) before asking question? :)

Comment: Perhaps look at pyinstaller

Comment: @BlueRineS i literally said "**i tried pyinstaller, but...**"

Comment: If `Pyinstaller` is not including everything, then you need to specify what it should include by using a `.spec` file.